# Is there a way that Users can have options to disable comments on their Blog Post?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am going through a Django tutorial and I am making a personal blog app , like users can create blogs and comment on it.

**Question**

I have built the comment system and Now i think, what if a user don't want to let other users make comments on his/her blog. I mean , Is there a function of code in django ? , that users can decide they want comments on blog post or NOT.

I have searched it but i found nothing.

So if you know this function then Please tell me. I will really appreciate your Help

Answer (score 1):

There is not exactly any built in code for this. But you can make one.

Option 1. You can define one booleanField for eg. is_comments_disabled. If user ticks that option in the profile then you can easily make other functionality.

Option 2: Make one model and give one ArrayField. Whenever a user selects to comments disabled add that user inside the arrayfield. Now You can easily check for all the users if the comments is disabled for that post by the user or not.
Hope it gives you some way around to solve your problem.
Thanks.